# Select query returns "value: not positioned on a valid record" in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have been working on a small code which is supposed to fill up columns on a QTableWidget with values fetched from a SQL table.

Here's a small snippet:

```
QString path = "C:\\ENTRIES.db";
QString itemToSearch = "ABC"; //This comes as a parameter to a slot actually, assigning it here for simplicity
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(path);
db.open(); 

QSqlQuery query(db);
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM METADATA WHERE ITEM LIKE ':item %'");
query.bindValue(":item", itemToSearch);

if(query.exec())
{
    ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->setVisible(true);

    ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->clearContents();
    int rCount = ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->rowCount();

    while(query.next())
    {
        ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->setRowCount(rCount + 1);

        QTableWidgetItem *qtwParamName =  new QTableWidgetItem;
        qtwParamName->setFlags(qtwParamName->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
        qtwParamName->setText(query.value(0).toString());
        ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->setItem(rCount, 0, qtwParamName);

        QTableWidgetItem *qtwParamValue = new QTableWidgetItem;
        qtwParamValue->setFlags(qtwParamValue->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsSelectable & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
        qtwParamValue->setText(query.value(1).toString());
        ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->setItem(rCount, 1, qtwParamValue);

        rCount++;
    }
}
else
{
     qDebug() << "Error message: " << query.lastError().text() ;
     ui->tableWidgetSearchResults->setHidden(true);
}
db.close();
```

When executing `query.value(<index here>).toString());` lines, the Application Output prints:

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

I'm not sure of what I am missing here.

**Note:** I am using Qt 5.6, MSVC 2013 compiler and SQLite 3.8.

Comment: Your query does not return anything because parameters are not replaced *inside* SQL strings. But in any case, `next()` should never have returned true …

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by 'replaced inside strings'. Is it a reference to bind value?

Comment: Do you want to search `"ABC%"` or `"ABC %"` ?

Comment: This code results in the error "Parameter count mismatch"; the first branch of the `if` is never entered. @HariMohan, ensure that this is the code that you have actually compiled and that is actually executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CL. Thanks for the hint. I tried this line and it worked:

```
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM METADATA WHERE ITEM LIKE '" + itemToSearch + "%'");
```

Apparently `bindValue` was inappropriate in this case.