# QT Sql Error: Not positioned on a valid record

Tags: sql, qt, odbc

I am unable to run Select query using QODBC (don't need QMysql). They throw `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record`. However, other queries run fine.

There are other threads on the same issue on Stackoverflow. But none of them solves my problem. Here are a few

[QSqlQuery not positioned on a valid record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000123/qsqlquery-not-positioned-on-a-valid-record)

[Select query returns "value: not positioned on a valid record" in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973276/select-query-returns-value-not-positioned-on-a-valid-record-in-qt)

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver};DATABASE=dbname;");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("mysql");
if (!db.open()) {
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
} else {

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users where id=1;");
    if (!query.exec())
    {
        qDebug() << "SQL error: "<< query.lastError().text() << endl;
    }
    query.first();

    qDebug() << query.value("name").toString() ;

}
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Your query result is empty.  check for `query.first()`  as  `true` before you access `query.value("name")`

Comment: Yes after putting an ```if condition``` i get an error
```QSqlError("0", "QODBC3: Unable to fetch first", "[iODBC][Driver Manager]Optional feature not implemented")```

I am using a Mac. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Check Qt documentation for _QsqlQuery_ `prepare()` .. the issue could be there, with your specific OS/ ODBC driver . You can  also test directly `query.exec("SELECT id, name FROM users where id=1;");`

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. I skipped the prepare() statement and put the statement inside exec(). Any other way out please